# 3.5mm - mono connector to TRS jack type compatibility?

Tags: audio, connector

Is it possible to use the following together:

- 3.5mm mono connector with 2 conductors
- 3.5mm TRS jack with 3 conductors

In the order of going from source to an output device like speakers or to a computer.

Will it work fine (like mono)? What will be the resulting effect?

I can find information about going from stereo to mono but it seems hard to find info for the other way.

Comment: What signal is your TRS connector?  Balanced audio (mono) with shield or Stereo unbalanced?  Two completely different wiring schemes.

Comment: @DwayneReid uhh... can you clarify which you are referring to? TRS JACK? or MONO 2 COND. CONNECTOR? not sure if you can have balanced mono on 2 cond.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly: you have a mono source with a 3.5mm TS jack and you want to connect this to an input with a stereo 3.5mm TRS jack.

You can simply build a cable with the L & R channels tied together and connected to the mono signal. That is, sleeve to sleeve, tip on mono side connected to both tip and ring on the stereo side.

It will work fine; the audio will be mono.

Comment: so you are saying it will only be fine if I use an adapter of some sort?

Comment: No, no adaptor needed. Just solder the Tip and Ring tags on the TRS jack together and link straight to the Tip on the mono connector. Shield on one to shield on the other. Use single core coaxial cable. Simple.